# Handle webhook json input

Tags: php, json

I use this code to track a webhook (currently its saved a file, later I want to directly work with the data and then save usefull data in a database):

```
<?php

ob_start();
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$a = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'log.txt', $b, FILE_APPEND);
```

This is an example, what is written in the file:

```
string(1387) "{"action":{"id":"1234","idMemberCreator":"1234","data":{"list":{"name":"A third list","id":"1234"},"board":{"shortLink":"BcD","name":"Test Board","id":"1234"},"card":{"shortLink":"HfT","idShort":54,"name":"Test It","id":"1234","pos":108576},"old":{"pos":4952}},"type":"updateCard","date":"2015-04-14T13:24:51.759Z","memberCreator":{"id":"1234","avatarHash":"1234","fullName":"Peter","initials":"p","username":"peter"}},"model":{"id":"1234","name":"Test Board","desc":"","descData":null,"closed":false,"idOrganization":null,"pinned":false,"url":"http://test.de","shortUrl":"http://test.de","prefs":{"permissionLevel":"public","voting":"disabled","comments":"members","invitations":"members","selfJoin":false,"cardCovers":true,"cardAging":"regular","calendarFeedEnabled":false,"background":"blue","backgroundColor":"#0079BF","backgroundImage":null,"backgroundImageScaled":null,"backgroundTile":false,"backgroundBrightness":"unknown","canBePublic":true,"canBeOrg":true,"canBePrivate":true,"canInvite":true},"labelNames":{"green":"","yellow":"","orange":"","red":"","purple":"","blue":"","sky":"","lime":"","pink":"","black":""}}}"
```

(I changed all ids to 1234 for security purpose)

How can I e.g. get the id of the action or more difficult: The username of the user

I dont know what to do with the "string(1387)..."

Here is a json_decode of the input (I did it manually, but I want to do it with php):
http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/2aab86

Can somebody help me, to get this information?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you're using a Trello Webhook. Their requests jeson is not automaticly processed into the `$_POST`

Thus you need to manuly process the jason-daten:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input')
$action = json_decode($json, true);
```

You can than use it as normal json datan:

```
$action['action']['data']...
```

use this to see how the array looks:

```
echo "<pre>print_r($action,true)</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi :) I tried its that way, but it does not save the username into the log.txt file :/ http://pastebin.com/RnMrwAhA Is there anything wrong?